# What is the third note in the Devil's Tritone?

Tags: metal, metallica

I am a self taught musician (guitar/keyboards) with a limited knowledge of written music theory. For example if you asked me to play an augmented fourth I wouldn't know what you meant but if I observe you play it I would understand exactly what you were talking about.

Regarding the infamous "Devil's Tritone" that was banned by the church in the middle ages. To my mind tritone implies three notes,  yet I only know of two which are used extensively in Heavy Metal for the evil, doomlike quality it lends a composition (Enter Sandman by Metallica is an example: E/A#). Dependent on which key you are playing in - E/A# F/B F#/C G/C# and so on.

My question is all references and instances of this only seem to use two notes. What is the third note that composes the Devil's Tritone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weird thing about a tritone is that it isn't comprised of three notes, it's technically just an an interval of

> three whole tones

...hence the *tri tone*

in other words, 6 semitones, an augmented [sharp ♯] 4th or diminished [flat ♭] 5th, between only two notes...
... which makes your above 2-note comparisons absolutely correct - each of those is a tritone.

Where the 'devil' may be found, I'm not really sure.

There's nowhere else you can go with a tritone... add another 6 semitones to try make it more 'devilish' & you end up back at the octave.

The most famous example [imho] has got to be the intro to Purple Haze, by Jimi Hendrix.

The opening guitar riff is simply B♭ to its octave.
The bass, meantime, is letting us know we're rooted on E.
There's really nothing more to it - yet it's a game-changing noise.

Wikipedia has a mind-numbing explanation of a [Tritone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritone)
There's also a fair treatise on [Purple Haze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_Haze) itself

Comment: OK that makes sense, I still don't get what you mean by augmented 4th, but flattened 5th I understand, in the key of A the 5th is E so the flattened 5th is D# (Or E flat). I believe it was labeled the "Devil's Tritone" in the middle ages by the church and there was some ban on using this tritone in any compositions due to it's "Evil" sound . I'll do a bit of research into this and see if i can find some verification.

Comment: Halfway between a 4th & a 5th - in A that would be D & E - there's D♯/E♭. The *name* depends on what key you're in, but it's the same *note*., that note is 6 semitones [three tones] up from A. Whether you consider it to be an augmented [sharp] 4th or a diminished [flat] 5th also depends on what key you are in. They're all just different ways of describing the same interval

Comment: I think I've got it, sharps or flats, I always wondered what the criteria is for whether you should label a note or a chord a sharp or a flat for example when should you use D# instead of E flat.

Comment: I ought to tweak my answer to include aug=sharp, dim=flat. I maybe wasn't too clear.

Comment: Augmented = Sharp and Diminished = Flat, no that's cool I think I've got it, if someone asks me to play a diminished 5th I'll know exactly what they mean now. Thanks Tetsujin I've learned something today I didn't know yesterday.